# angularjs ngrepeat and ngif

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am new to angularjs I am trying to create a tab so I created an array of content like this

```
$scope.panels = [
        { title: "About",   url: "about", active: true  },
        { title: "Contact", url: "contact"              },
        { title: "Services",    url:"service"           },

    ]
```

And here is how I have implemented the loop

```
<li class="nav-tab" ng-repeat="panel in panels">{{panel.title}}</li>
```

Now I need to highlight the active tab by adding active class when active is true. How can I add `if(active== true)` then class should be like this **class="nav-tab active"**

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass#!

Comment: @Relicset take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to use [ng-class directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

The following code should work for you:

```
<li class="nav-tab" ng-repeat="panel in panels", ng-class="{active:panel.active}">{{panel.title}}</li>
```

Note that if you class have any `-` (dashes in its name) then you would have to wrap the class name in quotes (`''`) e.g. `ng-class="{'active-class':panel.active}"`.

I hope that will help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use either by two ways (mostly preferred [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass))

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YJQx6/8/)**

using `ng-class` ([**ngClass**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass))

```
        <li ng-class="{'active': panel.active, 'inactive': !panel.active}">{{panel.title}}</li>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YJQx6/7/)**

using `class`

```
        <li class="nav-tab {{panel.active==true?'active':''}}" ng-repeat="panel in panels" >{{panel.title}}</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `ng-class`,

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

```
<div ng-class="{'active-Class': isOpen, 'inactive-Class': !isOpen}">isOpen</div>
```